# Why LESS compiler wont recognize classes generated by zero iterator?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

My CSS sheet is required to reset some Bootstrap 3 preset values to make my desired style, thus I need utility classes like `.m-b-0` which set `margin-bottom:0px`.

But Less compiler I was using in grunt wont recognize classes `.m-b-0` generated by loop when I nested them in other class, but classes like `.m-b-1` and `.m-b-10` will be recognized correctly.

The loop code in my Less files is like this:

```
.m-loop (@i) when (@i <= @iterations) {
  .m-@{i}{
    margin: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-h-@{i}{
    margin-left: ~"@{i}px";
    margin-right: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-v-@{i}{
    margin-top: ~"@{i}px";
    margin-bottom: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-l-@{i}{
    margin-left: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-r-@{i}{
    margin-right: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-t-@{i}{ 
    margin-top: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-b-@{i}{
    margin-bottom: ~"@{i}px";
  }
  .m-loop(@i + 1);
}
.m-loop(0);
```

and I use the classes supposed to be generated in the same less file like this:

```
.panel{
  .m-b-0;
}
```

Then my compiler throwed

```
Running "less:production" (less) task
>> NameError: .m-b-0 is undefined in ../css/less/stylesheet.less on line     237, column 3:
>> 236   div.panel{
>> 237   .m-b-0;
>> 238   }
Warning: Error compiling ../css/less/stylesheet.less Used --force, continuing.
```

Is this forbidden to use zero valued iterator in Less compiling or where did I take it wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be a syntax error. I don't see an opening brace on this line:

`.m-t-@{i}`

See if that helps.

Comment: Sorry but it is an editing problem. The loop code is running. It generated desired CSS but will fail when I use generated classes in same LESS file by mixin/nesting.